# Mockito, mocking a constructor within a method of a class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Currently trying to write unit tests for a complicated system that uses a constructor within one of its method that takes itself as the parameter to inject into a database context and retrieve the correct object from the correct environment.

Trying to use Mockito to emulate this, and make it return a test object instead of it going to try and find it from the database; but i'm stumped as to how to make it work with traditional techniques and @InjectMocks + @Mock annotations.

The essence of the code is below:

```
public FooService{

public String fooFindObject(FooDefinition fooDef) throws FooDefinitionException{

FooFinder theFooFinders = new FooFinder(this);
Foo fooObj = theFooFinders.findFoo(fooDef);

//Logic to be tested inside here that will throw exception upon bad foo definitions

return fooObj.trackingId();

}
```

How could I mock this FooFinder object and make it return my own testing foo object so I can test the definition obj. Mockito is being used, and the possiblity of rewriting this code to use get/setters of the FooFinder obj is not allowed - it's not my code and I'm just there to test it.

Comment: You are explicitly asking JVM to create `FooFinder` instance. You can't mock it. If I were you, I could have modified my code so that `FooFinder theFooFinders` is a field. For the application, I would definitely use DI framework or worst case, I would have set it from a different class.

Comment: I agree, it would be a lot easier to use DI and supply it a mocked object, and I'll probably end up pushing a code commit to implement that if I can't find a solution.

Comment: A push which improves the testability should not be an issue for anyone. I am not sure about your constraints but give it a shot.

Comment: True, the issue is this is the FooService is a webservice and is instantiated by Spring and the dependencies are injected there so I'd have to change a lot more than just one class.

Comment: The structure of the code is what I would refactor first. This unfortunately is poor design. However, have you taken a look at PowerMockito?

http://benkiefer.com/blog/2013/04/23/powermockito-constructor-mocking/

Comment: I don't think you have to change a lot of classes! Create a bean of FooFinder, inject to FooService. You would not be need not have any change to any other class.

Comment: @RensGroenveld : Seems PowerMockito has something new. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome, let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: @RensGroenveld : Refactoring would be  a preferable approach for me in these cases than using new libraries. I would always prefer fixing the code over patching it. Put your comment as an answer SO may accept it.

Comment: I agree. If you need PowerMockito, usually you are better off refactoring your design. I'll put it as an answer :) thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128339/discussion-between-newuser-and-rens-groenveld).

Comment: This is a sign that you should rethink about your design.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library that extends upon Mockito: PowerMockito.

It allows you to do quite some more hacking than the usual Mockito. It's pretty sweet, but the thing is, if you need PowerMockito, your design usually smells.

I would definetely refactor your design. But if you can't do this for any reason, please take a look at constructor mocking with PowerMockito:

http://benkiefer.com/blog/2013/04/23/powermockito-constructor-mocking/

Comment: I mentioned PowerMockito in my question with the InjectMock and Mock annotations, it has not been of any help for me so far. I'd appreciate some sample code.

Comment: Your question only mentioned mockito implementations. Sample code can be found in the URL of my answer?